# JTable tearing when rendering

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have set up a `JTable` and have made it to contain 18 columns. Initially, when it was 13 columns, it fitted nicely into the `JTable` and there was no tearing. However, once I made it to contain 18 tables, and set autoresize to be off, when I use the horizontal scrollbar to try to scroll through the other columns, tearing of the `JTable` started to occur as can be illustrated by this picture:

[image: table image]

Netbeans also started to give me lots of error messages like these:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:689)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintForceDoubleBuffered(JComponent.java:1090)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.blitDoubleBuffered(JViewport.java:1598)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.windowBlitPaint(JViewport.java:1559)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.setViewPosition(JViewport.java:1102)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.hsbStateChanged(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1087)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.stateChanged(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:364)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:302)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:168)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setValue(JScrollBar.java:463)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI$TrackListener.setValueFrom(BasicScrollBarUI.java:1253)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI$TrackListener.mouseDragged(BasicScrollBarUI.java:1195)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6553)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3339)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6274)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4509)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:689)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:671)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:689)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintForceDoubleBuffered(JComponent.java:1090)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.blitDoubleBuffered(JViewport.java:1598)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.windowBlitPaint(JViewport.java:1559)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.setViewPosition(JViewport.java:1102)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.hsbStateChanged(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1087)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.stateChanged(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:364)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:302)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:168)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setValue(JScrollBar.java:463)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI$TrackListener.setValueFrom(BasicScrollBarUI.java:1253)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI$TrackListener.mouseDragged(BasicScrollBarUI.java:1195)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6553)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3339)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6274)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4509)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:689)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:671)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:689)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintForceDoubleBuffered(JComponent.java:1090)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.blitDoubleBuffered(JViewport.java:1598)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.windowBlitPaint(JViewport.java:1559)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.setViewPosition(JViewport.java:1102)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.hsbStateChanged(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1087)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.stateChanged(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:364)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:302)
    at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:168)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setValue(JScrollBar.java:463)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI$TrackListener.setValueFrom(BasicScrollBarUI.java:1253)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI$TrackListener.mouseDragged(BasicScrollBarUI.java:1195)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6553)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3339)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6274)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4509)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Why is this so? Are there any solution to this problem? Thanks!

So sorry! Here are the code used to initialize the table.Hope it will be useful!

```
jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTable jt = new JTable(data, column);// data and columns are just 2D and 1D String arrays each
    JTableHeader th = jt.getTableHeader();
    th.setBackground(java.awt.Color.pink);
    th.setEnabled(true);
    jt.setTableHeader(th);
    jt.setEnabled(false);
    jp.add(jt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jt, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    jt.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    scrollPane.setEnabled(false);
    jp.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: There is obviously something wrong in your code. The stacktraces you see are likely the cause of your problem. Post some code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you have declared more columns than there is in your data array.

This code sample reproduces exactly your problem:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTable {

    public JFrame f;
    private JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        String[][] data = new String[1][1];
        data[0] = new String[] { "hello" };
        String[] columns = new String[] { "Column-1", "Column-2" };
        table = new JTable(data, columns);
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The solution is of course to make the number of columns in your data match the number of column you declare. And you should make sure that each "row" of your data array is initialized with the correct number of "columns".

For example you could have this:

```
String[][] data = new String[1][18];
data[0] = new String[15]; // <-- This will cause some problems
```

Now, I would recommend to use another data structure than arrays, because it is not very flexible and they tend to get hard to maintain. A simple solution is to have some "Model" class and create your own TableModel like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public JFrame f;
    private JTable table;

    public class ModelObject {
        private String column0; // Consider using something more explicit than column0,1,...
        private String column1;

        public String getColumn0() {
            return column0;
        }

        public void setColumn0(String column0) {
            this.column0 = column0;
        }

        public String getColumn1() {
            return column1;
        }

        public void setColumn1(String column1) {
            this.column1 = column1;
        }
    }

    private class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<ModelObject> data;

        protected TableModel(List<ModelObject> data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "Header 0";
            case 1:
                return "Header 1";
            }
            System.err.println("Only two columns are known in this table model");
            return "???";
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            ModelObject o = data.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return o.getColumn0();
            case 1:
                return o.getColumn1();
            }
            System.err.println("Only two columns are known in this table model");
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        Random r = new Random();
        Vector<ModelObject> data = new Vector<TestTable.ModelObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ModelObject o = new ModelObject();
            o.setColumn0("Some stuff in column 0 " + i);
            o.setColumn1("Some other stuff in column 1 " + r.nextInt());
            data.add(o);
        }
        table = new JTable(new TableModel(data));
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Here everything is written in a single class, but of course you should separate them to properly follow the MVC-pattern.

Comment: This solved my problem! So silly of me... I declared the column number shorter than the real column number.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in this line:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14 at

It means it knows it's supposed to have more columns, and it wanted to draw the next column, but could not because the underlying table model did not have so many columns.

Giving a table 18 columns means you need to update the associated table model as well. Both need to be in synch for the table to work.

Comment: Hmm but the table model I am using is the default Table model... I didn't set any table model for it. How can I update the table model? Thanks for your help!